# Is there any Qt container that returns its values as comma separated string?

Tags: qt, containers, csv

In Qt, does one of the containers give me the option to return a comma-separated string from its values?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If your elements are `QString`s, you can use [`QStringList::join()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlist.html#join):

```
QStringList list;
list << "one" << "two" << "three";
QString s = list.join(",");
// s == "one,two,three"
```